# failedPrecondition error when authenticating with service account to Google API

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I'm trying to fetch a given email from my own inbox (as project owner) using the Google API 2.0.0 RC4 for PHP.

I have a project setup, a downloaded authentication file in JSON format and I have enabled the gmail API in the Google Developers Console.

But when I run the following code I get a "Bad Request" error with reason "failedPrecondition". Now this leads me to believe that there is something wrong with the access rights, but I can't figure out what I need to do here.

Code:

```
<?php
    require_once("google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC4/vendor/autoload.php");

    $client = new Google_Client();

    // set the scope(s) that will be used
    $client->setScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"]);

    $client->setApplicationName("MyProject");
    // set the authorization configuration using the 2.0 style
    $client->setAuthConfigFile("myAuthFile.json");

    $gmailHandle = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

    $messages = $gmailHandle->users_messages->get("myemail@mydomain.com", "12343445asd56");

    echo json_encode($messages);

?>
```

And the complete error looks like this:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason":
>   "failedPrecondition", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400,
>   "message": "Bad Request" } } '

Comment: Try using the string `"me"` instead of `"myemail@mydomain.com"` in the GET-request. Any difference?

Comment: @Tholle Unfortunately that gave me the same result. What would "me" refer to if I had multiple admins connected to my service account?

Comment: That's a very good question, my apologies. I didn't catch that is was a service account in the title. Maybe the email address has to be url-encoded, and the client library doesn't do it for you? If not, then I don't know :( `"@"` => `"%40"`

Comment: Didn't work either unfortunately :( One thing that caught my eye though is the "domain": "global", which is not really what I wan't since it's supposed to access accounts belonging to my domain. That's pretty much my only lead so far and I've tried tweaking the code for hours. When life gives you lemons, don't use the google API.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just ran into this and finally found the solution. You are getting that error because you are using a service account without specifying a "subject" as part of the configuration. That is required for the API to know which email address you are acting as when using the service account. You can see it attempting to use this subject in Google_Client::createApplicationDefaultCredentials

The solution is to add the following line in the code after you have called setAuthConfig()

```
$client->setConfig('subject', 'you@email.com');
```

Be sure to then use the keyword 'me' when fetching the messages from the inbox as you are now acting as the email address which you have configured as 'subject'.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! However, I find it weird that I have to specify it both as a param in users_message::get() and as a config variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was able to figure out the python api as a result of this. Same basic issue but api call is different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is also relevant to JS users https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/399#issuecomment-108562902