# How to retrieve Google Service Account Access Token .NET

Tags: .net, google-oauth, service-accounts

I need to retrieve an access token for a Google service account, then I'll use the token to get the results from Google Analytics. I've already did it in PHP but I'm struggling with .NET, I've used an example from the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account) but i'm having some issues. This is the code:

```
        private static String ACTIVITY_ID = "1111111";

        public static void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Plus API - Service Account");
            Console.WriteLine("==========================");

            String serviceAccountEmail = "*@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/*.p12"), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
               {
                   Scopes = new[] { PlusService.Scope.PlusMe }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));

            // Create the service.

            var service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Plus API Sample",
            });

            Activity activity = service.Activities.Get(ACTIVITY_ID).Execute();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes on the line:

```
Activity activity = service.Activities.Get(ACTIVITY_ID).Execute();
```

With the following error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Not Found [404]
Errors [
    Message[Not Found] Location[ - ] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]
]
```

What am I missing or doing wrong in order to get the Token? and also, is the `ACTIVITY_ID` the ID taken from the View in Analytics or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It might be about the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369850/465942) issue, you need to set the `User` property:

```
var xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.client_email)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/somescope" },
                User = "theuser@gmail.com"
            }.FromPrivateKey(cr.private_key));
```

Comment: Holy crap, dude...I've been looking for the User portion of the answer for TWO DAYS. If you want, post this as an answer to my similar vb.net question and I'll give you the bounty on it.

Comment: @SEFL If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40683953/465942) is your issue I think it's different? Will try to answer it for you :)

Comment: It is the issue...and the User property did answer it for me.